# Convert string type into Array List

Tags: c#, arrays, string, serialization

How can I convert a String like this into an Array List

```
 {'id':'6726','Codigo':'AlmNumTrab','Denominacion':'Almacen','Descripcion':'Almacenes','TipoCampo':'2','TipoIntroduccion':'0'}
```

I would like to get the id field directly like datos[0]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you didn't mention the language search google as key value array 

here the code for c# :

```
var Dictionary= new Dictionary<string, object>();
dictionary.Add("id", "6726");

object id= dictionary["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use the [Json.Net nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)
2. make a class `yourClassHere` (or copy paste json as class in visual studio) with matching properties.
3. use this code

Untested but should do the trick:

```
string yourStringIsJson = "{'id':'6726','Codigo':'AlmNumTrab','Denominacion':'Almacen','Descripcion':'Almacenes','TipoCampo':'2','TipoIntroduccion':'0'}";

yourClassHere deserializedThing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<yourClassHere>(yourStringIsJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON string. so best to treat it as such.

So With C# add the Newtosoft JSON library with NuGet.

then you can deserialise it to a Dictonary

```
var dict = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>("{'id':'6726','Codigo':'AlmNumTrab','Denominacion':'Almacen','Descripcion':'Almacenes','TipoCampo':'2','TipoIntroduccion':'0'}");
```

you can then access the values like this:

```
dict["id"] // this should give you 6726
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for your answers.

I finally found a solution in a simple line, is not an ArrayList but I think is better solution.

```
String idCampo = JObject.Parse(datos)["id"].ToString();
```

As you know this converts the string in an JObject and I can access it directly.

I will try your answers anyway, just for learning.